# .NET Map control for both Web and Windows application

Tags: asp.net, .net, wpf, gis

The client wants an interactive map in both a browser and desktop environments. The maps should also be usable in both online and offline scenarios. Meaning that if online a background like GoogleMaps or BingMaps is displayed otherwise it's just something local that gets rendered as background.

Our concern is code duplication: we want to write the least amount of code twice (JS for web vs c# for desktop) so a control that offers a higher level of abstraction (such as for example GMap.NET - which is unfortunately desktop only) would be great.

Does such control exist? Or would the easiest way be to look into a good web only control and embed it in a WebBrowser control?

Comment: You might take a look at the [XAML Map Control](http://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/). It is available for WPF, Silverlight and Windows Runtime. Only the WPF version supports offline map out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we already had a license for the Infragistics suite, we went with their Silverlight "Geographic Map Control".

**I would not recommend this** (Infragistics): While writing a very basic POC, I encountered 1 serious visual bug (since fixed) + one piece of code had to be rewritten in a very specific way (THEIR way) because my alternative solutions were all extremely slow.

I have not checked the XAML Map Control Clemens suggested (a project he is involved with) because we needed offline map in Silverlight aswell.